# TextField paints dark when typing on iOS Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I am having this problem at the login page of my app, when I start typing on the email `TextField` the background of the text becomes dark and I cant figure out why, this only happens on iOS not on Android, here is the image:

[image: Bloqued text]

Any idea why this may be happening here is the code of my text field:

```
child: ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
    valueListenable: _wrongEmail,
        builder: (context, wrong, _) {
        return TextField(
        cursorColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        focusNode: myFocusNodeEmailLogin,
        controller: loginEmailController,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
        inputFormatters: [
            FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(' '),
        ],
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: Global.size.fontSize(2.0),
            color: Theme.of(context).textSelectionColor,
        ),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: InputBorder.none,
        icon: Icon(
            wrong ? Icons.clear : Icons.mail,
            color: wrong
                ? Colors.red
                : Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            size: Global.size.hp(4.0),
            ),
            hintText: "Correo Electrónico",
            hintStyle: TextStyle(
            fontSize: Global.size.fontSize(2.0),
            ),
          ),
        );
     }),
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: add these  filled: true,fillColor: Colors.white, in decoration.

Comment: tell me if this work for you.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, but It didn't work also did try adding `Colors.transparent` but the problem remains